# Jupyter issue with python / pyspark versions

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am running a Jupyter notebook using the pyspark kernel. I am getting the following error. How can I force Jupyter (ideally from within Jupyter) to use the right driver?

*Python in worker has different version 2.6 than that in driver 2.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions*

Thank you

Hani

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem in your pyspark **kernel.json** configuration. For example my pyspark kernel is located at:

```
/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json
```

and contains:

```
{
 "display_name": "pySpark (Spark 1.6.0)",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/local/bin/python2.7",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {
  "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/local/bin/python2.7",
  "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/lib/spark",
  "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:/usr/lib/spark/python/",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py",
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master yarn-client pyspark-shell"
 }
}
```

It is **very important** to point the same python version in both places (**argv** and **PYSPARK_PYTHON**).

Hope that helps!